# Can blender use 100% CPU when baking to speed up baking?

Tags: particles, baking

Can blender use 100% CPU when baking to speed up baking? When I was baking particles, CPU usage is around 50-60% usage and take many hours, is it possible to use 100% CPU to reduce baking time. Does the reason behind this is because using multiples cores haven't implement to particle baking yet or that is not the problem?

I don't really know about programming sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Odd.. All of my cores go to 100% when baking particles. What kinds of particle dynamics are you baking, and what version of blender are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.69 latest version form official blender website. I am baking particle as emitter not hair. Particle physic is fluid. In particle render setting dupli object is metaball. So basically I am trying to simulate water with particle and metaball.

Comment: Blender particle system baking is single threaded, nothing you can do about that.

Answer (score 4):

No, there's nothing you can do about that until multi-threading is implemented for particle baking.

...except use a single-core processor.