# How can I fully utilise all CPU cores for a hair dynamics bake?

Tags: animation, particles, baking, hair, cache

I am working on a huge grassy field using a hair particle system that has 500,000 hairs. I have some forcefields blowing the grass around. When I bake this particle system to the disk, one of my CPU cores shoots up to 100 percent and the others stay around 5%. The grass blades don't interact with each other at all. Is there a way to make it use all 8 of my CPU cores, and if so how?

I have an i7-6900k and I'm on Ubuntu 17.10 using Blender 2.79. I have 16GB of RAM, but am considering an upgrade especially if it would help with this situation.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7425/can-blender-use-100-cpu-when-baking-to-speed-up-baking/